# How can I assign a function into alert action?

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I want to add UIAlert in my game.

There is a reset() function and i want to put it into Alert

When i click Reset, i want to call reset() function

```
@IBAction func showAlert (sender : AnyObject){
    var alert = UIAlertController(title :"alert",
                                message : nil,
                         preferredStyle : UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "RESET", 
                                  style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, 
                                handler: {(action -> reset())} 
}
```

I tried it in this way but // action -> reset() // there is a problem and i couldnt find how i should write

Comment: You say 'it does not work', in what way? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Yes, my @IBAction func doesnt work and gives error

Comment: I was asking in which way it doesn't work - we can't help diagnose and fix your problem if we don't know what the problem is :)

Comment: I am trying to create a UIAlert and put in it a action which is assigned reset()  function, 
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "RESET", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: {(action -> reset())} }
Compiler says it is wrong and i am asking where is my wrong :D sorry for English

Comment: This question is a lot of things.  "Clear" is not one of those.  What does "reset" mean?  What do you expect to happen when the button is tapped?   What is happening?  Is it compiling?  Is it crashing?  Are there warnings or errors?  If there are, what are they?  Is `reset` a method of your class somewhere that you should be including?  And answering in comments does not suffice.  You need to edit the question into good shape, or it will be closed.

Comment: Ok, sorry i cant explain clearly
Hopefully, it is done now.

Answer (score 1):

I m not sure if it's the problem, but I would have right something like this:

```
@IBAction func showAlert (sender : AnyObject){
  var alert = UIAlertController(title  :"alert",
                               message : nil,
                               preferredStyle : UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

  alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "RESET",
                                style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default,
                                handler:{ $0 in reset()}))
}
```

Note the difference in writing the handler. 
$0 refers to the first parameter of the callback, there are others ways (more detilled) to write it but in your case this should be enough

Comment: You could also replace `$0` with `_` since you're not using it.